# Implicitly allow requests in IIS from valid hostname

Tags: security, http, iis

I have a few publicly accessible IIS servers and sites (personal and corporate), these hosts have own domains/subdomains, and all legit access to these https sites happen through domains.

Almost all HTTP app vulnerability scans from bots/rooted servers happen to the servers through IP, without valid hostname, and if there is hostname it is the default reverse DNS host, not the actual domain of the site.

**Is there a way in IIS to implicitly only allow requests with proper hostname?** The site root app only has bindings to the hostname, but IIS still accepts requests, and responds with 404. The best thing would be to timeout the request similar fashion as if the site doesn't have HTTP open.

I of course understand that this does not guarantee anything in security wise, the scanner can still figure out the proper hostname in many ways, but it would still filter out 90% of dummy scans.

IPS in firewall can probably do some things, but in some cases I do not have that luxury. Is there way in IIS? Redirect the http request to oblivion? (this would probably just change the error to proxy gateway http errors?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a global setting to disallow any requests with a "valid" hostname, but you can try the following

Create a new fallback site on your IIS server, while all other sites require hostnames this site is bound to all Unassigned IP addresses without any hostnames.

So any http requests to the server without an otherwise bound hostname end up on this site which just has a simple static html page.

For this site edit the `IP Address and Domain Restrictions`, don't add a new entry, just go to `Edit Feature Settings...` :

[image: IIS IP Restrictions]

Set the default access to `Deny` and then the `Action Type` to `Abort`

This way no response is send to the client. You also have the options to send a 401, 403 or 404 instead, but if you want no response, use `Abort`

There may be other ways to accomplish this, but this should work pretty well.

Comment: Great! This solution does work probably the best IIS can do. Unfortunately abort does return "connection reset" to client, which tells the bad actor that service exists open in this port, but at least it is not giving out IIS headers etc.

Comment: Extra note that "IP Address and Domain Restrictions" was not installed by default to IIS. You need to add it as IIS feature from windows features (Web Server (IIS) -> Web Server -> Security -> IP and Domain Restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `IHttpModule` that checks this.

**Register the module**

```
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <add name="MyModuleToBlockRequestsWithoutSNI" type="NoSniBlockerModule" />
   </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

**Hook the event during initialization**

```
public class NoSniBlockerModule: IHttpModule
{
   public void Init(HttpApplication httpApplication)
   {
      // Register event handlers
      httpApplication.BeginRequest += OnApplicationBeginRequest;
   }
}
```

**Check for SNI**

```
private void OnApplicationBeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var request = HttpContext.Current.Request;

   if (!SniPresentInRequestHeader(request))
   {
      // return the standard 400 Bad Request
      context.Response.StatusCode = 400;
      context.Response.StatusDescription = "You're missing the SNI wtf";
      context.Response.End();
      return;
   }
```

Comment: For someone scanning the http, 400 response tells that something is here. In this case I would like it to work so that there is no response at all.

Answer (score 0):

The design of IIS requires incoming HTTP requests to be dispatched to sites that contain the matching bindings. More details can be found in posts like [this](https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html). So in IIS there is no way to implicitly only allow requests with proper hostname, but explicitly.

If "IIS still accepts requests, and responds with 404", that means some site on this server still matches those requests and you should find that site first and choose from the following,

- Disallow this site to handle such requests by modifying its bindings.
- Use URL Rewrite module to abort such requests or return custom errors (404 or any other).
- Turn off this site if you don't need it.

Comment: Please provide context to the external link.